# Не срабатывают свойства при адаптиве

Tags: css

Делаю адаптив, указываю  @media (max-width: 900px) , задаю  классе параметры  , но когда ширина достигает этого значения они не срабатывают, показывает их перечеркнутыми, почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас код с @media (max-width: 900px) стоит выше чем обычный css код. Возможно файл shops.css подключается после style.css. Нужно поменять очередность.

вот статья про [Очередность в CSS](https://webformyself.com/ocherednost-v-css-kogda-poryadok-v-css-imeet-znachenie/)

Comment: Спасибо большое , помогло!)

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте очередность как указано в комментарии товарища. Обратите внимание что подключение к стилям происходит в `head` или поменяйте свойства блока местами в медиа запросе `@media all and (min-width: 900px)`

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!)